# Why does my wire value return null when running in connectedCallback method?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript

I have an LWC component on a record page which generates a signed URL for an external system, in order for my Apex method to generate the signed URL I need the Order Number from the Record (Order.OrderNum__c), instead of querying this in the Apex I would like to retrieve this using the wire service within the component and then pass to my Apex method.

Using the code below I'm able to retrieve the field I need and print it out on my LWC page, however the `connectedCallack` method returned undefined.

Can someone explain why this is and how I can resolve this?

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getSignature from "@salesforce/apex/iFrameUtils.generateSignedUrl";
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

import ORDER_NO from '@salesforce/schema/Order.OrderNum__c';
const fields = [ORDER_NO];
export default class PaymentGateway extends LightningElement {

    @track loaded = false;
    @track url;
    @api recordId;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
    order;

    get orderNo() {
        return getFieldValue(this.order.data, ORDER_NO);
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log(this.orderNo, 'this.orderNo');
        getSignature({ ref1_value: '$orderNo'})
            .then(result => {
                console.log('got back a result!');
                console.log(result);                
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('error occured');
                console.log(error);
            });
        this.loaded = true;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connectedCallback() lifecycle hook fires when a component is inserted into the DOM. Considering that the wired `getRecord` method does not fire at the same time or even before connectedCallback, it is normal that you are getting `undefined` values when invoking `getSignature`. A better approach would be to  use renderedCallback with a condition that determines if `getSignature` should be fired or to actually have a wired `getSignature` which is fired when `orderNo`'s value changes, for example:

```
@wire
(getSignature, { ref1_value: '$orderNo'})
wiredSignature({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            //do something
            }
        else if (error) {
          //do something else
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take the imperative call out of the `connectedCallback` and use 2 wired methods. I wouldn't use a `renderedCallback` either. First `@wire`:

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
order;
```

This will query for the order and return your `ORDER_NO` field when the `$recordId` changes (Assuming the recordId is for an order).

Now you are assuming that the getter invokes the second wire - which I'm not sure it will - check this, and if it doesn't just extract the order number to a regular var and use that as the reactive var below.

```
@wire(getSignature({ ref1_value: '$orderNo'}))
getSignature({ ref1_value: '$orderNo'})
.then(result => { /*your stuff*/ })
.catch(error => { /*your stuff*/ });
```